# Counting the number of occurrences in Python

Tags: python

I have a list with `0`, `1` and `2`,
I want to create a dict with the count of each.
This is my code,

```
count_map = {}
for i in my_list:
  if i in count_map:
     count_map[i] += 1
  else:
     count_map[i] = 1
```

My question is how can I write this code more pythonically.

Comment: `collections.Counter(my_list)`

Comment: has anyone been able to decide whether questions like these should be answered by an answer or a comment? I am still struggling

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I'm new to Python and trying to learn the style guidelines, is SO only for advanced users?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `collections.Counter` to do that for you:

```
from collections import Counter
count_map = Counter(my_list)
```

You can type cast it to `dictionary` by using `dict(Counter(my_list))`

Answer (score 2):

I would increment value in your dictionary this way in one line:

```
count_map = {}
for i in my_list:
  count_map[i] = count_map.get(i,0) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a dict cmprh :

```
l=[1,1,1,2,1,2,5,4,2,5,1,4,5,2]
{i:l.count(i) for i in set(l)}
```

Output :

```
{1: 5, 2: 4, 4: 2, 5: 3}
```